# What is the difference between var map=HashMap<Int,String>() and var map=HashMap<Int,String>(n)?

Tags: kotlin

Consider `n` is any integer with any particular value in the range of `Int` data type. so What is the difference between `var map=HashMap<Int,String>()` and `var map=HashMap<Int,String>(n)` ?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html), `var map=HashMap(n)` specifies the initial capacity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`HashMap(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-int-) overload accepts the *initial capacity*, which is used to initialize the `HashMap` with the provided capacity instead of the default one (which is rather small to reduce memory usage, 16 in JDK 8).

Use it when you know how many items you are going to put into the map, at least approximately, because it allows you to avoid overhead of re-allocating the map and re-hashing the keys as you put entries into it